# MetaOverflow: Stack Exchange related ATOM feeds

Tags: app, rss

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

[MetaOverflow](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) provides specialised RSS feeds for the Stack Exchange sites. Currently is provides two feeds related to the availability of sites, but more feeds for other things will be added over time.

#### To Use

[MetaOverflow](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) is hosted on Google App Engine. To use, simply go to the [front page](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) and choose the feed(s) you want, and subscribe to them with your RSS reader (such as Google Reader).

#### Platform

[MetaOverflow](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) is a web-based service, hosted on [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine).

### Contact

MetaOverflow is created by [Evan M<sup>c</sup>Lean](http://www.michevan.id.au/). My [web site](http://www.michevan.id.au/) lists various ways to contact me, including Twitter, identi.ca or via a [contact form](http://www.michevan.id.au/contact).

### Code

The application is written in Java, hosted on Google App Engine, <strike>and uses the Stack4J library</strike>. It is (currently) closed source. My motivations where:

1. Writing something useful for myself and the Stack Exchange community.
2. Gain some experience programming on Google App Engine.

### Update 14 Dec 2012

I have finally got around to updating [MetaOverflow](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) so it uses that latest Stack Exchange API, so the RSS feeds have started working again.

Comment: +1 - Very nice and clean offering for an obvious real world use case, I subscribed immediately :) Would you mind sharing what libraries you have used for implementing the feeds, if any?

Comment: No library used. I just generate the XML fragment for each entry and store the bytes. To assemble the feed, I write the preamble bit of XML, then each entry, then the closing XML - all to a ByteArrayOutputStream, which then gets poked into memcache so repeated calls for unchanged data can get a quicker response.